# Android studio: Where should I put a binary file to read with object RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, android, io

I'd like to open a binary file containing in a form of array. To access randomly, I used RamdomAccessFile. I put the file in the same folder as the java class file is in. I wrote the code as follows:

```
File file = new File("table.bin");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
```

But console says 'no such file or directory'. Then I moved to assets folder and got the same message. It worked well when I used this code in regular(not Android Studio) java file, with 'table.bin' in the same folder.

Where in the project folder do I have to place the file in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where in the project folder do I have to place the file in?

If you are looking to ship this file with your app, put it in `assets/`. However, bear in mind that this is a file *only* on your development machine. It is not a file on the device. On the device, it is merely an entry in your APK file. You can get an `InputStream` on this via `AssetManager`.

If you absolutely need this to be a file — you need `RandomAccessFile`, you want to modify the contents, etc. — use the `InputStream` to make a copy of the data to a file on the local filesystem, such as on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Then, you can work with that file.